# Django many-to-many relationship to self with extra data, how do I select from a certain direction?

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many

I have some hierarchical data where each Set can have many members and can belong to more than one Set(group)

Here are the models:

```
class Set(models.Model):
    ...
    groups = models.ManyToManyField('self', through='Membership', symmetrical=False)
    members = models.ManyToManyField('self', through='Membership', symmetrical=False)

class Membership(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey( Set, related_name='Members' )
    member = models.ForeignKey( Set, related_name='Groups' )
    order = models.IntegerField( default=-1 )
```

I want to know how to get all the members or all the groups for a Set instance.
I think I can do it as follows, but it's not very logical, can anyone tell me what's going on and how I should be doing it?

```
# This gives me a set of Sets
# Which seems to be the groups this Set belongs to
set_instance.set_set.all()

# These give me a set of Memberships, not Sets
set_instance.Members.all()
set_instance.Groups.all()

# These they both return a set of Sets
# which seem to be the members of this one
set_instance.members.all()
set_instance.groups.all()
```

Comment: Hold on, this is throwing errors on `runserver` but didn't on `shell`
I'll look into it and post again...

Comment: I had to remove `members` from `Set`, but the rest seems to act the same.